# Loading custom shape with json in kinetic js

Tags: javascript, json, file, shapes, kineticjs

How can I load a custom shape ( such as http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-kineticjs-shape-tutorial/) with a Json file through Kinetic JS.

I managed to load normal shapes but for this one there's no documentation.

Comment: did you see this one http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-load-complex-stage-with-kineticjs/

Comment: I believe you have read tutorial . You simply need to put config json in new Kinetic.Shape(XXX).

Comment: show some code of what you have achieved, vs what you want to achieve

Comment: For example, the json file of a regular polygon looks like this: "x": 10, "y":20, "radius":30, ...  however for a custom shape (like the link above) with quadraticCurves, functions are needed. What would the json file look like in that case ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `Kinetic.Shape` for that, use a [`Kinetic.Path`](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-kineticjs-path-tutorial/). A `Kinetic.Path` gets a `data` member that allows to specify the shape of a polygon using the [SVG PathData](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathData) format. The [documentation on kineticjs.com](http://kineticjs.com/docs/symbols/Kinetic.Path.php) unfortunately is very thin -- the W3 site contains lots of examples worth checking out.

Of course, this is not as flexible as code; however, it looks promising: [This](http://jsfiddle.net/StefanHanke/WwTvj/) is exactly the same figure as in the [custom shape tutorial](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-kineticjs-shape-tutorial/), using only one `Kinetic.Path`.

Comment: Thanks for this new vision of solving this problem. I haven't thought of it !!! And it seems to be really the best solution !!! :) You made my day !!